# Regular Expressions first Alphabetic rest alpanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex
What I need is:

- To start only with: A-z (Alphabetic)
- Min. Length: 5
- Max. Length: 10
- The rest can be A-z0-9(Alphanumeric) but contain at least one number

What I have: `^[A-z][A-z0-9]{5,10}$`

Comment: And what is the issue you are facing with current regex?

Comment: You need to use positive lookbehind for the at least one number requirement.

Comment: So your issue is about the number requirement?

Comment: Wait, does it mean you allow any char in the string after the first letter? Just there must be one digit later? Or should the string be alphanumeric only? Try `/^(?=.{5,10}$)[a-zA-Z]\D*\d\D*$/` if you want to allow any chars (but if you do not expect line break chars in the input).

Comment: @FabrizioStellato My issue is how to determinate characters after first, to validate them for A-z0-9.
Or spilt the validation for 2 steps 1 - just the first character 2- the rest of the string and 3 - the whole string just for length

Comment: Your question is still not clear: what can be there inside the string, except the first letter and a digit somewhere inside?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated my question, the rest are alphanumeric but contain at least one number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=.{5,10}$)[a-z][a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*$/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZLIkP3/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{5,10}$)` - the string should contain 5 to 10 any chars other than line break chars (this will be restricted by the consuming pattern later) up to the end of string
- `[a-z]` - the first char must be an ASCII letter (`i` modifier makes the pattern case insensitive)
- `[a-z]*` -  0+ ASCII letters
- `\d` - 1 digit
- `[a-z\d]*` - 0+ ASCII letters of digits
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var ss = [ "ABCABCABC1","ABCA1BCAB","A1BCABCA","A1BCAB","A1BCA","A1BC","1BCABCABC1","ABCABC","ABCABCABCD"]; // Test strings
 
var rx = /^(?=.{5,10}$)[a-z][a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*$/i;                  // Build the regex dynamically
document.body.innerHTML += "Pattern: <b>" + rx.source
          + "</b><br/>";                               // Display resulting pattern
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + rx.test(ss[s]) + "</b><br/>";
}
```

Comment: BTW, as for the `[A-z]`, please see [*Why is this regex allowing a caret?*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: so is better to use in future `[a-z]` but keep `/i` to turn of the case sensitivity?

Comment: You may use `/[a-zA-Z]/` and `/[a-z]/i` interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pattern = /^[a-z]{1}\w{4,9}$/i;

/* PATTERN
^ : Start of line
[a-z]{1} : One symbol between a and z
\w{4,9} : 4 to 9 symbols of any alphanumeric type
$ : End of line
/i : Case-insensitive
*/

var tests = [
  "1abcdefghijklmn", //false
  "abcdefghijklmndfvdfvfdv", //false
  "1abcde", //false
  "abcd1", //true
];

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  console.log(
    tests[i],
    pattern.test(tests[i])
  )
}
```

Comment: This allows strings without digits and also allows `_`.

Comment: `{1}` is never needed

Comment: You can also add a lookahead to your solution which makes it work too with also changing your `\w` to `[a-z\d]` for disallowing underscore: [`/^[a-z](?=\D*\d)[a-z\d]{4,9}$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/1m2Smm/1). Vote for the basic idea.